# Laravel - Cannot serve a .png image stored in my database as a base64 encoded string

Tags: php, image, laravel, png

I created a png image for a div on my page using HTML2Canvas, which creates a base64 encoded string for the image. I display it on the page as an inline:

```html
<img id="headerImage" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." width="60">
```

I then save it in my database as a *LONGTEXT*.

In my controller, I seem unable to server the image back as a valid PNG. Tried a bunch of different ways, as evident in the code snippet:

```html
                $imageStr = $plan->image;

                $pos = strpos($imageStr, ',');
                $trimmed = substr($imageStr, $pos+1);

                $image = base64_decode($trimmed);

                /*
                $im = imagecreatefromstring($image);
                if ($im !== false) {
                        header('Content-Type: image/png');
                        imagepng($im);
                        imagedestroy($im);
                } else {
                        echo 'Failed';
                }

                return;
                */

                $response = Response::make(trim($image), 200);
                $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');

                return $response;

                /*
                return Response::stream(function() use ($image) {
                        echo $image;
                        }, 200, array('Content-Type:image/png'));
                */
```

When I look at the headers, it looks reasonable:

```html
t=4102 [st=437]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                       --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                           Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 16:36:28 GMT
                           Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
                           X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
                           Cache-Control: no-cache
                           Set-Cookie: [362 bytes were stripped]
                           Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
                           Connection: Keep-Alive
                           Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                           Content-Type: image/png
t=4102 [st=437]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
```

In all cases, the browser shows a broken image symbol. Getting to my wit's end at this point - appreciate any ideas on how to do this!

Comment: Your code should work as is, used it with converted PNGs and it worked just fine. How does the process you use to encode the images look like? What do you get if you just do an echo on `$imageStr`?

Comment: If I log the response that I return to the log file, delete the HTTP headers and save the remaining as a .png file, I can load that in the browser just file as a .png image. I decided to just save the image to disk (as that might be best for the long run anyways), and serve that up when needed.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd... Just to rule things out; what browser are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome. Thanks anyways - I have moved away from that implementation, and dont think of it as an issue anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should work as it is.

A note about Base64-encoded images; to decode them again, you have to remove the `data:image/png;base64` part of the string.

So:

```
<?php
$imageStr = $plan->image; // Or wherever you get your string from
$image = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imageStr));

$response = Response::make($image, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');

return $response;
```

Also, `imagecreatefromstring` is superfluous in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus - I do strip out the data:... with the *substr* command.

Comment: See comment on "main question", your problem here is odd indeed =/

Comment: Ok, it works but... Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: To put it simply; the `data:image/png;base64`-part is just so that the browser knows to interpret the string as an image. But reversing it back to a png, the data isn't a part of the actual image – it just causes the file to be scrambled and invalid.